# Change copy task destination

Tags: gradle

I would like to change the destination dir for file copy depending on the chosen build. 
This does not work since the task graph is executed in execution phase but the copyTask is set in configuration phase.

How can I achieve this?

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    println('taskGraph')
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(buildRelease)){
        File toDir=file('test/r')
        println('Copy to: ' + toDir.getName())
    }else if (taskGraph.hasTask(buildDevel)) {
        File toDir=file('test/d')
        println('Copy to: ' + toDir.getName())
    }

}

task buildDevel (dependsOn: ['copyTask']){}
task buildRelease (dependsOn: ['copyTask']){}

task copyTask(type: Copy) {
        from "test"
        into toDir
        include 'a.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help You (You need to create `a.txt` file on the same level as `build.gradle` is located:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->

   def cp = project.copyTask
   if (taskGraph.hasTask(buildRelease)){        
      cp.into 'lol1'
   } else if (taskGraph.hasTask(buildDevel)) {
      cp.into 'lol2'
   }
}

task buildDevel (dependsOn: ['copyTask']){}
task buildRelease (dependsOn: ['copyTask']){}

task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from file('.')
    include 'a.txt'
}
```

This will also work:

```
task buildDevel 
task buildRelease 

buildDevel.doFirst {
   cp('lol1')
}

buildRelease.doFirst {
   cp('lol2')
}

def cp(to) {
   copy {
    from file('.')
    into to
    include 'a.txt'
   }
}
```